# How is the IdentifyingNumber determined for an application in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

When I run the PowerShell command:

*Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "NameOfApplication"}*

It returns output similar to:

IdentifyingNumber : {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
Name              : NameOfApplication
Vendor            : VendorName
Version           : 1.0.2.2546
Caption           : Caption

When I install the application on another PC, the IdentifyingNumber is the same, I was wondering how this was determined by Windows (10 & 11 specifically)? Also, am I able to get this number without installing the software?

Comment: [The product code (also referred to as the identifying number) is determined by the GUID of the MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup#:~:text=For%20some%20strange%20reason%20the%20%22ProductCode%22%20is%20referred,Codes%20From%20A%20Remote%20Computer%20%22%20section%20below.) What non-programming problem are you trying to solve by knowing the identifying number of an application?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was interested in getting a PowerShell script to uninstall applications based on the product code for Intune. From the research I have conducted, I need an uninstall command that usually has this number that matches what is in the registry, and the uninstallstring. I was hoping to standardize everything for deploying new computer with select software installations.

Comment: You can get the information from the MSI for the application

Comment: [Please Stop Using Win32_Product To Find Installed Software. Alternatives Inside!](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/).